# Mac Os 10.13 logs me out randomly | Help reading logs

Tags: macos, crash, nvidia, macos-high-sierra

Apparently out of the blue, I have started to experience random crashes on my Mac Pro 4.1, flashed to 5.1. It's running High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G9016), with 48Gb of Ram and two cards (one GT120 and a flashed MacVidCard Titan X Pascal). It is a soft crash in the sense that it just logs me out of my session and then I need to log in again, so it doesn't completely reboot.

However it's very annoying since I can't finish any task properly and need to reopen all the files I might be working with, which generally deal with heavy graphics (CAD applications or video editing).

I am not fluent in reading crash logs, so any help reading this one is much appreciated. 
Here's the last crash log:

```
Process:               WindowServer [144]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               600.00 (312.103.11)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           WindowServer [144]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2019-11-17 18:15:12.313 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G9016)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        B4B1B7C1-08E2-6A09-6684-E949A6C2D95F


Time Awake Since Boot: 230 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000016
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x16:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000108ebe000-0000000108ebf000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW   [/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer]

Application Specific Information:
StartTime:2019-11-17 18:11:36
GPU:NV
MetalDevice for accelerator(0x4507): 0x7fb86ae03ef8 (MTLDevice: 0x7fb86c004800)
MetalDevice for accelerator(0x4e07): 0x7fb86d00d858 (MTLDevice: 0x7fb86c004800)
IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IOU0@3/IOPP/PXS1@0/NVDA,Display-B@1/NVDA
IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IOU1@7/IOPP/PXS2@0/NVDA,Display-A@0/NVDATesla

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libGPUSupport.dylib             0x00007fff6606b10c gpumRestoreTextureData + 60
1   libGFXShared.dylib              0x00007fff56f366d9 gfxUploadPluginTextureLevel + 111
2   GLEngine                        0x00007fff57bf55e7 gleSynchronizePluginTextureLevels + 279
3   GLEngine                        0x00007fff57bbfaaf gleBindFramebuffer + 321
4   GLEngine                        0x00007fff57b0855c glBindFramebuffer_Exec + 142
5   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f32ec24 CaptureSurfaceGL::CreateAndAttachTextureToFBO() + 162
6   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f32e3d8 CaptureSurfaceGL::PrepareForPopulation(CGRect, WSPixelFormat, float, bool, CGColorSpace*, CGXDisplayDevice*, unsigned int) + 74
7   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f444601 WSCALayerBackingUpdateFlatteningIfNeeded + 1284
8   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f3cd2b3 CGXNextSurface + 3246
9   com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f472211 generate_layers_for_window_surfaces(CGXRedrawState*, CGXWindow*, CGSOrderOp, unsigned int, int*, WSCompositeSourceLayer**, CGSRegionObject*) + 5581
10  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f46cca6 generate_layers_for_window(CGXRedrawState*, CGXWindow*) + 3193
11  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f46afc1 CGXUpdateDisplay + 13505
12  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f467882 update_display_callback(void*, double) + 257
13  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f4ae552 run_timer_pass + 495
14  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f4dc1c9 CGXRunOneServicesPass + 247
15  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff6f4dcd84 SLXServer + 832
16  WindowServer                    0x0000000108ebedde 0x108ebe000 + 3550
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff75559015 start + 1


Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff756aa28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75871009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75870be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff756a020a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7569f724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff4d4cb685 0x7fff4d41c000 + 718469
3   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff4d4cb813 0x7fff4d41c000 + 718867
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75871661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7587150d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75870bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.coreanimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff756a020a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7569f724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff5890ae62 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 870
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff5890aae6 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75871661 _pthread_body + 340
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7587150d _pthread_start + 377
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75870bf9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff756aa28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75871009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff75870be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fb871800000  rbx: 0x00007fb86c0e8800  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007fb86f832a00  rsi: 0x00007fb86c0e8800  rbp: 0x00007ffee6d40380  rsp: 0x00007ffee6d40320
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x000000016f236ee7  r10: 0x0000000000000003  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00007fb86f832a00
  rip: 0x00007fff6606b10c  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000016

Logical CPU:     4
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
      […]

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 3
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 318
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=380.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=380.3M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.6G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.6G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
CG backing stores                173.6M      139 
CG framebuffers                    1.0G        9 
CG framebuffers (reserved)        56.1M        9         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CG image                           668K        9 
CoreAnimation                     64.1M       53 
CoreGraphics                         4K        2 
Dispatch continuations            32.0M        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                           321.3M      146 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       13 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            160K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
OpenGL GLSL                        256K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        6 
Stack                             10.0M        6 
VM_ALLOCATE                       1352K       50 
__CGSERVER                           4K        2 
__DATA                            51.1M      249 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
__GLSLBUILTINS                    2588K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       194.5M       10 
__SLSERVER                           4K        2 
__TEXT                           185.8M      250 
__UNICODE                          560K        2 
mapped file                       25.8M        3 
shared memory                      180K       15 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.1G      965 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.1G      965
```